# How can I Enrol Certificate for TPM Virtual Smart Card by C#

Tags: c#, tpm

I already setup the Server and created the TMP template. Also create TPM virtual smart card on different machine belong to same network. I could manually enrol new certificate (certmgr console), but I need to do through the code. Is there any way to handle it by C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if my question not clear, but I found the solution and post it here.

I found two links which really helpful:

[How to create a certificate request with CertEnroll and .NET (C#)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2008/09/05/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-and-net-c/)

[How to generate a unique and uncopyable VPN certificate/key for a specific client hardware device?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179409/how-to-generate-a-unique-and-uncopyable-vpn-certificate-key-for-a-specific-clien)

```
objPrivateKey.ContainerName = "TestContainer";
objPrivateKey.ProviderName = "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider";
objPrivateKey.ProviderType = X509ProviderType.XCN_PROV_RSA_FULL;
objPrivateKey.Length = 2048;
objPrivateKey.Pin = "12345678";
objPrivateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_KEYEXCHANGE;
objPrivateKey.KeyUsage = X509PrivateKeyUsageFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_ALL_USAGES;
objPrivateKey.MachineContext = false;
objPrivateKey.CspInformations = objCSPs;
objPrivateKey.Create();

//  Initialize the PKCS#10 certificate request object based on the private key.
//  Using the context, indicate that this is a user certificate request and don't
//  provide a template name
objPkcs10.InitializeFromPrivateKey(
    X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser,
    objPrivateKey,
    ""
);

// Key Usage Extension 
objExtensionKeyUsage.InitializeEncode(
    CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_KEY_USAGE |
    CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_NON_REPUDIATION_KEY_USAGE |
    CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_KEY_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE |
    CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_DATA_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE
);

objPkcs10.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)objExtensionKeyUsage);

// Enhanced Key Usage Extension
objObjectId.InitializeFromValue(oid.Text);
objObjectIds.Add(objObjectId);
objX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage.InitializeEncode(objObjectIds);
objPkcs10.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)objX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage);

// Template Extension
objExtensionTemplate.InitializeEncode(templateName.Text);
objPkcs10.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)objExtensionTemplate);

//  Encode the name in using the Distinguished Name object
objDN.Encode(
    "CN=AlejaCMa",
    X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE
);

//  Assing the subject name by using the Distinguished Name object initialized above
objPkcs10.Subject = objDN;

// Create enrollment request
objEnroll.InitializeFromRequest(objPkcs10);
strRequest = objEnroll.CreateRequest(EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64);
```